# How to transfer data from worksheet to worksheet while preserving hyperlinks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two separate Google Worksheets -- I want to simply transfer the data from the destination to the source.  I've always used the code below to do this & it has always worked well:

```
function dataImport2() {
 //@NotOnlyCurrentDoc
var values = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id').
getSheetByName('All').getRange('c1:m').getValues();
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('All').
getRange(1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);

}
```

In this particular case, the data in the source is a mix of strings and number values, some of which have HYPERLINKS attached.

I realized, this code does not keep the hyperlinks on the cells when transferred.

I'm trying to build a code that would transfer all of the info, but also keep the links -- doing some reading it seems like getRichTextValues would help, but haven't been able to recreate.

This is where I'm at now:

```
function dataImport() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id').getSheetByName('All');
  var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('All');
  var range = sourceSheet.getRange('C1:M');
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues();
  
  for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < formulas[0].length; j++) {
      var formula = formulas[i][j];
      var linkUrl = formula.match(/"(.*?)"/);
      if (linkUrl !== null) {
        var richTextValue = richTextValues[i][j];
        richTextValue.setLinkUrl(linkUrl[1]);
        destinationSheet.getRange(i+1, j+1).setRichTextValue(richTextValue);
      } else {
        destinationSheet.getRange(i+1, j+1).setValue(formulas[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any thoughts as to how I could accomplish this transfer, while preserving hyperlinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following 2 patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the values are copied with `setValues` and "Method: spreadsheets.values.update" of Sheets API. So, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services. The reason for using Sheets API is to reduce the process cost by avoiding that `setValue` and/or `setRichTextValue` are not used in a loop.

```js
function dataImport() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id').getSheetByName('All');
  var destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var destinationSheet = destinationSS.getSheetByName('All');
  var range = sourceSheet.getRange('C1:M' + sourceSheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getValues();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var richTextValues = range.getRichTextValues();
  destinationSheet.getRange(1, 1, richTextValues.length, richTextValues[0].length).setRichTextValues(richTextValues);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values: values.map((r, i) => r.map((c, j) => richTextValues[i][j].getRuns().some(e => e.getLinkUrl()) ? null : (formulas[i][j] || c))) }, destinationSS.getId(), "All", { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `copyTo` is used.

```js
function dataImport() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id').getSheetByName('All');
  var destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var temp = sourceSheet.copyTo(destinationSS);
  var range = temp.getRange('C1:M' + temp.getLastRow());
  var destinationSheet = destinationSS.getSheetByName('All');
  range.copyTo(destinationSheet.getRange("A1"));
  destinationSS.deleteSheet(temp);
}
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.update](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update)
- [copyTo(spreadsheet) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [copyTo(destination) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

Comment: This is a phenomenal solution to my issue.  I'm unsure why I couldn't get the first script to pull hyperlinks (with API enabled), but the second solution worked flawlessly and very quick. Many thanks